# laravel - Query Builder vs. Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this statement, which is working fine but not as good as I want:

```
        $recipes = DB::table('recipes')
            ->join('category_recipe', 'recipes.id', '=', 'category_recipe.recipe_id')
            ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'category_recipe.category_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.user_id')
            ->where('category.id', '=', $cat_id)->get(array('recipes.*','users.*'));
```

How can I translate this to Eloquent?

**Why?**
I want to use one view for multiple methods.
This view or the foreach looks like this:

```
        @foreach($recipes as $recipe)
        {{link_to_route('recipe_details',$recipe->title,array('id'=>$recipe->id))}} - By {{ $recipe->user->firstname }}  - Category: @foreach($recipe->category as $cat) {{ $cat->title }} @endforeach </br>
    @endforeach
```

As you can see, I'm using the "user" relationship. Obviously this foreach doesn't work with the Query at the top, because there is no "user" model.

So how can I translate the Query into Eloquent?
I tried

```
$recipes = Recipe::with('category')->where('category_id',$cat_id)->get();
```

But this doesn't work. Any hints please?

**Here are my models:**
Recipe.php

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
public function category() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category','category_recipe');
}
```

Category.php

```
    public function recipes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe');
}
```

User.php

```
    public function recipes() {
        return $this->hasMany('Recipe','user_id');
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$recipes = Recipe::with(array('user', 'categories' => function($q) use ($cat_id) {
    $q->where('id', $cat_id);
}))->get();
```

Changes following:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category','category_recipe');
}
```

To (`category` should be `categories` in `Recipe.php`):

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category','category_recipe');
}
```

Btw, you may also use `join` like this (Using `Eloquent` model, if you need in any case):

```
Recipe::join('category_recipe', 'recipes.id', '=', 'category_recipe.recipe_id')
      ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'category_recipe.category_id')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.user_id')
      ->where('category.id', '=', $cat_id)->get();
```

**Update:** You may also try this:

```
$recipes = Recipe::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($cat_id) {
    $q->where('id', $cat_id);
})->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. WIll try it out. I tried the join method but this still doesn't make §recipes->user->firstname work and i need it wor the other methods. But ok, I try your first suggestion! :)

Comment: `§recipes->user->firstname` won't work because `get()` returns a collection so you need to use `first()` to get the first item and if there are more than one items then you may use a loop. Try, `§recipes->first()->user->firstname` for the first one.

Comment: Your version seems to work but I cannot do the "where" properly. It shows me ALL rows instead of (in this case) just two for the category ID = 6. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/AnEuXRfc

Comment: Then it should be a different method using `whereHas` if you only want to get rows with categories.

Comment: You may also add a `->where('category.id', $cat_id)->get()`.

Comment: One question more: Do you have an Idea, how I join the same table again for some results? Right now, cat_id points to each category for itself, thats great. But the main(parent)categories are not exactly part of the results. When someone clicks on ID = 5, he get all the recipes which are in this category. If someone clicks on ID = 1 (which is the parent of a lot more categories) I need not just the recipes of this particular category but from all related too. Do you have an idea?