# Laravel - Eloquent Self Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

a lot of my models and other code is here and related to this question:
[laravel - Query Builder vs. Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813989/laravel-query-builder-vs-eloquent#22814968)

I have this query:

```
        $recipes = Recipe::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($cat_id) {
        $q->where('category_id', $cat_id);
    })->with('user')->get();
```

Works great if I choose (example) ID = 5. I get all recipes which have category_id = 5.

**What if...**
Let's say, the category_id = 5 has the parent with the id = 1 (Main categories have ID 1-3 and all children have 4 to x).

I need now, that if someone clicks the main category, in this case, ID = 1, that I can get ALL recipes that are related to the main category including the children. So I get all from Category 1 and all from 5 (and so on).

I have NO clue, how I can set the relationship or built the query.

Second is, that I also need to implement this function into the "advanced search" method of the website, but I think, if I can solve this question, the rest is "easy".

Help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the `title` and details you described in your question makes me think that, you want to create a relationship to the model itself using another field/column of the same model and the `id` field and in this case you may create such a relationship using something like this:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

According to this relationship, your `categories` table should contain primary key `id` and another field as `category_id` to make relation so, if an `id` is `1` and if `category_id` contains the `1` then there is a relation between `id=1` and `category_id=1`.

I've written an article a few days ago on this same thing, you may read that to get the better idea that I'm talking about: [LARAVEL – MODEL RELATIONSHIP TO ITSELF](http://heera.it/laravel-model-relationship#.Uz2zgvmSySo).

Comment: The relationship is already there. I have a parent_category and child_categories methods, so this is fine. I need to select all related categories including the main category in my sql statement or Eloquent / Query .

Comment: That's exactly I've answered, `id` is the parent and `category_id` is the child items, did you read the article ? You should read that to get the idea, I've used it in a similar thing.